# Redux: Child receiving props before parent

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My app has a state which may or may not have a `user` object.

I have two containers and two components:

ParentContainer:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  showUserDetails: Boolean(state.user),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentComponent)
```

ParentComponent:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ showUserDetails }) => (
  <div>
    {showUserDetails && <ChildContainer />}
  </div>
)
```

ChildContainer:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  name: state.user.name,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent)
```

ChildComponent:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name }) => (
  <h1>{name}></h1>
)
```

However I am running into scenarios where, after an action which sets `state.user = null`, `ChildContainer` tries to render before `ParentContainer` and hence throws an exception as it can't access `null.name`.

Is this expected behaviour of Redux, that a child container can re-render before the parent? In the classic React flow, this error would not happen.

I appreciate in this contrived example one could just call `<ChildComponent name={user.name} />` in the `ParentComponent` instead of using a container. But in the real world I have deeply nested components accessing a lot of different parts of state, so can't just pass props down easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you batching your Redux dispatches? If not read v3.0.0 release notes carefully:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v3.0.0

It suggests `redux-batched-updates` module but it's more or less deprecated in favor of [redux-batched-subscribe](https://github.com/tappleby/redux-batched-subscribe)

Use it like this:

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates as batchedUpdates } from 'react-dom';
import { batchedSubscribe } from 'redux-batched-subscribe';

const store = createStore(reducer, intialState, batchedSubscribe(batchedUpdates));
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Any good places to learn about what batching updates is and why it solved this problem?

Comment: @BenSmith  In short the idea in batching is that multiple setState calls during the same js tick will produce only one render in React. For why it causes problems checkout the original Github issue https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/86 The exact same thing is happening there as you have here.

Answer (score 1):

The update will happen regardless of the child component being contained in a parent or not. Since it is in the DOM at the time of the update, the `connect` will try to update your component.

The easiest workaround for this would be to insert a safety check when pulling the user's name (`state.user.name,`) and replace it with (`state.user && state.user.name,`).

Or, of course - the alternative. Passing it down from the parent.

To further explain, the props that are being sent down from the parent will first be evaluated in the parent and then the updates would propagate downwards in the hierarchical tree. However, since your prop of `name` is actually coming directly from the state tree, you will need some safety checks around it.

Even if the parent after a subsequent update of it's own will decide that the child should no longer be rendered (since `showUserDetails` will now evaluate to false).